# How do I check db query returned results using PHP's PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How do I check if my result set is empty using PDO in PHP?

```
$SQL = "SELECT ......... ORDER BY lightboxName ASC;";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
$STH->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $lightbox_name = $row['lightboxName'];
    $lightbox_id = $row['lightboxID'];
    echo '<option value="'.$lightbox_id.'">'.$lightbox_name.'</option>';
}
```

I used to do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...... ORDER BY lightboxName ASC;");
if(!$result) { echo 'No results found!'; }
```

But have just started using PDO and prepared statements and checking against `$STH` does not seem to work as expected — it always has value!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try to use [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
$rows_found = $STH->rowCount();
```

But, according to the manual:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

If it does not work for you, you can use the other method mentioned in the manual.

You can of course also set a variable before your `while` loop, change it in your loop and check the value after the loop...

Comment: Perfect. Works as intended. I was just reading about this and another way to do it is to use columnCount(). Do you think there is a performance difference between rowCount() and columnCount()?

Comment: @ShadowStorm `columnCount()` should be super-fast, but then again, `rowCount()` as well if it is available. You'd have to test that to be sure.

Comment: I've found `columnCount()` works best because it will return `0` under all of my test cases. `rowCount()` often returns the rows modified and throws off my logic.

Comment: What's "the other method mentioned in the manual" you make reference of?

Answer (score 0):

Just dump information about variable.

```
var_dump($STH)
```

**EDIT**

I just got the question. There is [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function for that. Just use  `$STH->rowCount();` for the row count then compare it.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question! I don't want to dump my variable. I want to check if database query returned results!

Comment: do something like return $result, and then print_r()

Comment: @mk_89: I don't have a $result variable, I have $STH variable and it always contains data whether it has a result set or not.

Comment: I just got the question. There is rowCount() function for that. Do $STH->rowCount();

Comment: Thanks mate. I edit my vote. Somebody else answered before you so I will accept their answer unfortunately. Thanks tho'.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the code it does work and finally after a few hours of looking around and mix matching some answers here is one that will in fact return a count on your select statement.
SQL is the select statement obviously
$username1 is the post of the text box for username.
$password1 is the same as the username setup.
Other than that you should have everything you need to make it work simply substitute your variables in place of mine. I hope this saves some people time as I searched a while trying to get exactly what I wanted here.
This solution is for when you have a select statement and you want to be able to continue or stop based on it returning something.

```
SQL = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE Username = :Username AND Password = :Password';
STH = $conn->prepare($SQL);
STH->bindParam(':Username', $username1);
STH->bindParam(':Password', $password1);
STH->execute();
STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


row_count = $STH->rowCount();
```